# WEEKNUM across multiple years

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am doing a cohort analysis for a subscription service from September 2021 - January 2023 and using the WEEKNUM formula, but of course each year starts on a different day and I am struggling to figure out how to mitigate this for all dates on the worksheet. Additionally, I just want there to be 52 weeks each year (not 53, week 52/1 can overlap years).
Presumably it will need to be some sort of IF statement but I just can't seem to visualise it!

I have tried =WEEKNUM(D2,15), which is fine for days in 2021 as it starting on a Friday, but not for days in 2022 and 2023 when I drag the formula down all of the dates

Comment: *Additionally, I just want there to be 52 weeks each year* Not sure if that's possible because 365/7 is greater than 52 so there is alway a partial week 53. I'm afraid you'll need a custom calculation for these. If you know how manually you would do it then you can use formulas for that. I suggest you add an input and expected output (explaining **why** that output)

Comment: Are there an exact number of days? Nature has it sorted, but we want simple numbers...

Comment: Please share your expected output

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured out the answer!

=IFS(D2<>"*2023*",(WEEKNUM(D2,1)),D2<>"*2022*",WEEKNUM(D2,16),D2<>"*2021*",WEEKNUM(D2,15))

I have tested it against some of the dates manually and it seems to hold true